# HTML emails using javamail are inconsistently sending quotes

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

So I'm trying to send a message through Javamail but I get inconsistent quotes on the receiving end. When I look at the HTML file in chrome it looks exactly how I want it to, but when I send the email, some of the quotes end up looking like question marks. I am nearly 100% sure the encoding is correct, but here is my java code...

```java
String message = //an html file that I import as a string

javax.mail.Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
//other things
msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

My HTML code looks like this (note: it's a microsoft outlook template that I am editing)...

```html
<li class=MsoNormal style='color:black;mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:
 auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo3;tab-stops:list .5in'><span style='font-size:
 10.5pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Select
 the desired times.&nbsp;<b>Make sure</b>&nbsp;that multi on-call (to the
 right) is switched to &quot;Yes&quot; and click &quot;Save&quot;<o:p></o:p></span></li>
```

I know its formatted really badly, but I'm not sure how to make it look any better. Anyway, in the last line, there is the `switched to &quot;Yes&quot; and click &quot;Save&quot;<o:p></o:p></span></li>`. When I view the html on chrome, it appears as it should

```
switched to "Yes" and click "Save"
```

but when I send thee email through javamail it looks like

```
switch to <?>Yes<?> and click <?>Save"
```

It would be understandable if only all the quotes became , but one of them, in the actual case of my program two, actually format correctly. I am so confused by this. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Does the html in the mail message contain literally the ASCII characters "&quot;"?  If so, I can't explain why sending it through JavaMail would cause a problem.  But if the html text contains the actual quote characters, you have to make sure to get all the character encodings right in the html content and in the Content-Type for the message.

Comment: @BillShannon my html literally contains the character "&quot".

Comment: You mean the character**s**, right?  That's 6 ASCII characters that represent a single quote character.  If you just use a single ASCII double quote character, does it work?

Comment: I originally had a single ASCII double quote but the program came up with the current error. I retried with the characters "&quot" and nothing changed.

Comment: If it displays ? for ", something else is seriously wrong.  I doubt it has anything to do with sending the message through JavaMail.  Try sending plain text instead of text/html and see how that's displayed.  Try simplifying the html content to get rid of all the CSS styling.  What are you using to view the message?  A web browser accessing Gmail or something like that?

Comment: I figured it out. I was importing the code through Files.readAllBytes and that messed with the code somehow. When I copied the literal contents of the html file into msg.setContent everything started working correctly